# How to design state based on useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-reducer

I have the below requirement:

We have a fleet of **10 trucks**. Each truck can carry different loads, for our use case **the load is medications**.
A **Truck** has:

- serial number (100 characters max);
- model (Lightweight, Middleweight, Cruiserweight, Heavyweight);
- weight limit (500gr max);
- battery capacity (percentage);
- state (IDLE, LOADING, LOADED, DELIVERING, DELIVERED, RETURNING).

Each **Medication** has:

- name (allowed only letters, numbers, ‘-‘, ‘_’);
- weight;
- code (allowed only upper case letters, underscore and numbers);
- image (picture of the medication case).

And from my assessment, it is best to use a useReducer to achieve the aim. But my challenge is how to construct my state.

1. Should I nest the medication part, or should it stand alone?

```
    const [truck, setTrucks] = useState([
            {
                sn: "001001",
                model: "LightWeight",
                weightLimit: "50",
                batteryCapacity: 80,
                state: "IDLE",
            },
            {
                sn: "001002",
                model: "Middleweight",
                weightLimit: "150",
                batteryCapacity: 30,
                state: "IDLE",
            },
            //rest data here
        ]);
```

2. How will I present it in my reducer if it is nested:

```
    export const droneReducer = (state, action) => {
            switch (action.type) {
                case "REGISTER_TRUCK":
                    return [
                    ...state,
                    {
                      sn: action.truck.sn,
                      model: action.truck.model,
                      weightLimit: action.truck.weightLimit,
                      batteryCapacity: action.truck.batteryCapacity,
                      state: action.truck.state,
                    },
                  ];
                case "LOAD_TRUCK":
                case "CHECK_LOADED":
                case "CHECK_AVAILABLE":
                case "CHECK_BATTERY_LEVEL":
            }
        };
```

Thanks

Comment: Your #2 example doesn't show any handling of any nesting at all.

Comment: @TKoL Thanks for your reply. Yes it doesn't show, because I don't know how to do it. How will I do it?

Comment: Your `truck` state could include a `load` variable, which is an array of medications with qty, or something like that.

Comment: Hi @TKoL, if that is the case, how do you access it in the reducer

Comment: That would definitely depend on HOW you want to access it, and for what purpose. For example, let's say you wanted to remove a particular medication from a particular truck: you would write an action that takes an `sn` value, to find the truck, and a `code` perhaps, to identify the medication. You would find the truck with the right `sn` in the `state` array, and then get its inventory, `truck.load`, and then filter its load to no longer include any medicines of the provided code, then update the state accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comments, if you wanted it nested you would add a `load` property to the `Truck` object:

```
export const droneReducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "REGISTER_TRUCK":
                return [
                ...state,
                {
                  sn: action.truck.sn,
                  model: action.truck.model,
                  weightLimit: action.truck.weightLimit,
                  batteryCapacity: action.truck.batteryCapacity,
                  state: action.truck.state,
                  load: action.truck.load
                  // an array of medicines with qty
                },
              ];
            case "LOAD_TRUCK":
            case "CHECK_LOADED":
            case "CHECK_AVAILABLE":
            case "CHECK_BATTERY_LEVEL":
        }
    };
```

So it might look like `load: [{name: 'COVID vaccine', weight: 2, qty: 9000, code: 'CVD19'}]`

And then you would access it like you would access any other property of a truck: `truck.load`. You can view it's contents, filter it and reset the state with a new value, add stuff to it, remove stuff from it, change the qty of something inside it. Anything.

Comment: Hi @TKoL, thanks for your reply, I have seen what you posted above. I will try it. Actually, based on the actions, the second case is where I load the truck with the medications, the upper one is just to register the truck. I will implement it as you have stated above. Thanks